# Why am I getting error saying 'No JDK for Module' in java using InteliJ editor

Tags: java

[Attached is an screenshot of the error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no2qY.png)I am trying to write a simple program of Hello World and I am getting a error saying " error running 'main':
No JDK for module 'untitled 104' "

Answer (score 2):

file-> project structure-> sdk -> click on + icon and give jdk path here

Comment: [The screenshot attached is the window i got afterfollowingyour instructions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oggp.png)
So now which file path do i choose for the SDK and JDK Homepath?
Or what path do I really need to establish?
Im a newbie. Its my first Java project.